# How do I make webmock block/stub external requests from other gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, webmock

I'm trying to use webmocks to test part of my app that interacts with an external service. However, all of the API calls are actually happening within another gem. So it continues to make the requests, even though I've enabled webmock.

This properly is blocked and requires a mock:

```
it 'test webmock' do
  Net::HTTP.get("www.google.com", "/")
end
```

But the test which contains API requests against the gem, which should be calling the external service is not.

Any idea how to make that test also require a mock?

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/dezi-client

Comment: It should work fine. are you sure the request Dezi makes is invoked within the test block?

Comment: Yes I am. I used VCR and it captured the request quite well. Which is the solution I used in the end.